# Why my array gets overlaped

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple project where i am trying to learn the concepts of vue.js using componenetes, comunication between components(i use eventBus) i am using the webkit-simple template to approach this, basicly what happens, is that i have 1 component that consists in a simple textarea where i add some text, that text should be displayed in my second component, that is a template where i render a array with all my texts that i inserted, like a list of quotes.

**component addQuote**

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                    <label>Quote:</label>
                    <textarea v-model="quote.text" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button @click="addQuote" class="btn btn-primary center">Add Quote</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { quoteBus } from '../main.js';

    export default {
        methods: {
            addQuote() {
                if (this.counter < 10) {
                    this.counter++;
                    this.quote.key =+ new Date();
                    quoteBus.$emit('saveQuote', this.quote);
                }
            }
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                quote: {},
                counter: 0
            }
        },
        created(){
            quoteBus.$on('decreaseCounter', () => {
                this.counter--
            });
        }
    }

</script>

<style scoped>
    .row {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .center {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    div .text-center {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

**component quotes**

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="(quote,$index) in quotes" @click="deleteQuote($index)" :key="quote.key">
            <div class="spacing">
                <h2>{{quote.text}}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { quoteBus } from '../main.js';

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                quotes: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            deleteQuote(i){
                this.quotes.splice(i,1);
                quoteBus.$emit('decreaseCounter');
            }
        },
        created() {
            quoteBus.$on('saveQuote', quote => {
                this.quotes.unshift(quote);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(this.quotes));
            });
        }
    }

</script>

<style scoped>
    h2 {
        font-family: 'Niconne', cursive;
    }

    div .col-md-3 {
        border: 1px solid darkgray;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    div .row {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .spacing {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

the problem is, everytime i add a quote the text replace all the elements before.

**Example:**

9th entry: text: "abcdef", all the entries in the array has this value in text, all my divs has the value of abcdef, what is happening :S

Comment: try `{{quotes[$index].text}}` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const quoteBus = new Vue();

Vue.component('addQuote', {
  template: '#addQuote-template',
  methods: {
    addQuote() {
      if (this.counter < 10) {
        this.counter++;
        this.quote.key = +new Date();
        quoteBus.$emit('saveQuote', Object.assign({}, this.quote));
      }
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      quote: {},
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  created() {
    quoteBus.$on('decreaseCounter', () => {
      this.counter--
    });
  }
});

Vue.component('quotes', {
  template: '#quotes-template',
  data: function() {
    return {
      quotes: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteQuote(i) {
      this.quotes.splice(i, 1);
      quoteBus.$emit('decreaseCounter');
    }
  },
  created() {
    quoteBus.$on('saveQuote', quote => {
      this.quotes.unshift(quote);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.quotes));
    });
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="addQuote-template">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                    <label>Quote:</label>
                    <textarea v-model="quote.text" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button @click="addQuote" class="btn btn-primary center">Add Quote</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template id="quotes-template">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" v-for="(quote,$index) in quotes" @click="deleteQuote($index)" :key="quote.key">
            <div class="spacing">
                <h2>{{quote.text}}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <add-quote></add-quote>
  <quotes></quotes>
</div>
```

The problem is that there is only one instance of `this.quote` in your `addQuote` component. You pass that particular object to `quotes` to be put into the array every time. When an object is put into an array, it is by-reference. If you put the same object into an array multiple times, you just have multiple references to the object's contents. Every element of your array is a reference to the same set of contents.

You need to send a copy of the object instead:

```
quoteBus.$emit('saveQuote', Object.assign({}, this.quote));
```

Comment: wokred like a charm, can you explain it better to me, so you say that everytime i create a object i add the same reference to it, so when i unshift another object it overwrites the object before because of the reference?

Comment: I've reworded my answer to try to make it more clear.

Comment: i get it why it has that behaviour, i just don't get 1 thing, if i create a object every time i add a new quote, why did it reference the same object? what make it have that behaviour?

Comment: normally it happens if i do something like this: var myObj = {text: "someText"], var anotherObj = myObj, anotherObj.text ="someText"

Comment: You were not creating a new object every time you added a new quote. You were emitting `this.quote`, which is what got unshifted into the quotes array. The `{}` in my answer is a new object, and `Object.assign` copies values into it.